# Quando usar condição ternária?

Tags: condição, estilo-de-codificação, formatação-condicional

Eu particularmente gosto do uso de condição ternária, mas vejo por aí muitos desenvolvedores se dizendo contra, existe até regra no CheckStyle ao validar seu código que te encoraja a não usar.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var idElemento = $(this).attr("id");
var isDataInicial = idElemento.contains("Inicial");
$("#" + (isDataInicial ? idElemento.replace("Inicial", "Final") : idElemento.replace("Final", "Inicial"))).datepicker("option", isDataInicial ? "minDate" : "maxDate", selectedDate == "" ? null : selectedDate);
```

Tirando o fato que se algo mais tiver que ser implementado quando a condição der verdadeira e/ou falsa teremos mais trabalho para desfazer o ternário e criar a estrutrua `if/else` não vejo problema algum no código acima, talvez uma melhor formatação no máximo, mas em uma linha foi resolvido o problema que sem o ternário teríamos algo como:

```js
if ((idElemento.contains("Inicial")) {
    if (selectedDate == "") {
        $("#" + idElemento.replace("Inicial", "Final")).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    } else {
        $("#" + idElemento.replace("Inicial", "Final")).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate)
    }
} else {
    if (selectedDate == "") {
        $("#" + idElemento.replace("Final", "Inicial")).datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
    } else {
        $("#" + idElemento.replace("Final", "Inicial")).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate)
    }
}
```

Então fica a pergunta, quando devemos usar o ternário? E é tão ruim assim usar ternários aninhados com uma boa identação?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A sua cadeia de `if` proposta não é a única maneira de se representar o mesmo código:

```js
var idElemento = $(this).attr("id");
var isDataInicial = idElemento.contains("Inicial");

var idEscolhido, opcaoDP, data;
if ( isDataInicial ) {
    idEscolhido = idElemento.replace("Inicial", "Final");
    opcaoDP = "minDate";
}
else {
    idEscolhido = idElemento.replace("Final", "Inicial");
    opcaoDP = "maxDate";
}
if ( selectedDate == "" )
    data = null;
else
    data = selectedDate;

$("#" + idEscolhido).datepicker("option", opcaoDP, data);
```

O código acima é mais extenso, porém mais legível que ambas as alternativas. Apenas no caso de `data`, é que se ganharia alguma coisa usando o operador ternário:

```js
var data = (selectedDate == "" ? null : selectedDate);
```

(parênteses opcional, mas eu sempre coloco quando uso o operador ternário em uma única linha, para ênfase)

Dito isso, não tenho nada contra o uso do operador ternário sempre que isso trouxer **clareza** e **concisão** ao seu código. Mesmo no caso de múltiplas condições, ele pode ser colocado de uma forma bem formatada, fácil de ler:

```js
int result = FirstCheck() ? 1 : 
             SecondCheck() ? 2 : 
             ThirdCheck() ? 3 : 
             0;
```

O que torna seu exemplo original problemático é que você usou **3 vezes** o operador ternário **em uma única linha**. Isso não só torna difícil de ler, mas também difícil de depurar (i.e. se você precisar colocar um *breakpoint* e/ou um `console.log` para inspecionar o comportamento do seu programa, fica inviável fazê-lo nesse formato).

Comment: Concordo com você que depurar em JS seria uma tarefa quase impossível a menos que você isolasse em consoles.log cada um dos ifs ternários, agora com as IDEs em Java atuais você nem precisa usar sysout (equivalente a um console.log) pra isso. Porém gostei do uso dos parênteses para enfatizar o ternário.

Answer (score 11):

Recomendo usá-lo somente quando a instrução resultante é extremamente curto e representa um aumento significativo na concisão sobre o if/else equivalente sem sacrificar a legibilidade.

Bom exemplo:

```
int result = Check() ? 1 : 0;
```

Mau exemplo:

```
int result = FirstCheck() ? 1 : SecondCheck() ? 1 : ThirdCheck() ? 1 : 0;
```

Antes de usar o operador ternário, você deve considerar a complexidade da situação em mãos. Evite aninhar ou empilhar suas operações, mesmo se você estiver confortável com eles, pois isso pode levar a um código muito confuso e resultados não intuitivos. Ainda é melhor usar declarações IF para situações complexas. Acima de tudo, ter um codigo agradável para o próximo cara que for mexer e tentar manter seu código limpo e fácil de entender.

Comment: Acho que é um pouco de questão de gosto mesmo, esse mau exemplo que você deu e eu também vi muitos concordando lá no SO eu acho simplesmente muito mais fácil de ler. Em uma olhada entendi que são três condições e quais saídas de cada uma. Até concordo que ternários aninhados podem levar à certa confusão, mas se você olhar meu exemplo eu não os usei aninhados, porém usei três ternários diferentes em uma linha só.

Comment: Como você disse é questão de gosto, e se você trabalha em grupo pode conversar com o pessoal de trabalho e ver oque eles acham melhor...

Comment: Aqui eles usam o CheckStyle que eu falei no início.

Answer (score 11):

Robert Cecil Martin, autor do livro Código Limpo, sugere logo no primeiro capítulo a seguinte métrica para a qualidade de um código fonte: a quantidade de vezes que você escuta seus colegas dizerem `"WTF"` enquanto revisam o seu código (é sério!).

Já para o computador, tanto faz. Como você mesmo expôs de certa forma na pergunta, em geral a forma:

```
a ? b : c;
```

É equivalente a:

```
if (a) { b; } else { c; }
```

Já que a máquina é indiferente, o que define a "melhor" e a "pior" forma para cada caso é legibilidade e a facilidade de manutenção. Isso varia de situação para situação. E possível que ambas se alternem como a "melhor" forma em pontos diferentes de um mesmo arquivo de código. Se você programa em equipe, converse com seus colegas para que cheguem a um consenso e padrão. Se você programa sozinho, releia códigos que você tenha escrito no passado, e veja a forma que lhe é mais fácil de entender.

Revendo melhor a pergunta, consigo pensar em duas situações nas quais uma forma é melhor que a outra.

**Quando temos muitas condições que queremos testar**, um `if` pode ser mais legível.

```
if ((a == null &&
        b != null &&
        c ^ d) ||
        (e && !f) ||
        g)
{
    foo();
}
else
{
    bar();
}
```

Se escrito da forma ternária, ficaria:

```
((a == null && b != null && c ^ d) || (e && !f) || g) ? foo() : bar;
```

Você pode continuar adicionando condições até que a expressão fique maior que a tela. Quebrar em linhas pode ficar estranho na forma ternária.

Note que isso foi um caso hipotético e **ilustrativo**. É muito melhor criar uma variável booleana calculada como resultado de todas as condições, quando são muitas, e então usar essa variável no `if` ou na expressão ternária.

**Código em linha** é onde a expressão ternária se demonstra particularmente útil. Por exemplo:

```
int a = foo(b ? c : d);
```

É mais compacto do que:

```
int a;
if (b)
{
    a = foo(c);
}
else
{
    a = foo(d);
}
```

Embora isso pareça com a comparação anterior, note a diferença sutil: você não pode usar um bloco `if` **dentro da chamada de um método ou função** (pelo menos na maioria das linguagens da família do C - não posso fazer uma afirmação veemente para todas as linguagens).

Comment: Bem legal sua resposta também abordando um novo aspecto. Eu também não uso ternários com condições longas demais, na verdade nem com IF eu uso condições grandes demais, tento sempre isolar em variáveis para o código ficar mais legível como você mesmo sugeriu.

Answer (score 1):

Tive dúvida quanto ao uso do ternário e, considerando a grande facilidade que o ternário pode trazer, além de hoje ter melhorado a visualização (este stack é sobre Javascript, mas o PHP traz em alguns novos paradigmas), a seguinte estrutura:

```
var valor = (acao == 1)
    ? primeiroValor
    : ((acao == 2)
        ? segundoValor
        : terceiroValor);
```

Com essas padronizações, como citei o PHP, existe as [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/), que buscam a padronização do código e, vendo que uma unidade existe entre a comunidade, diminuir as chamadas "*Questões de gosto*"