# Quando devo usar o operador "?" em C?

Tags: c, operadores, condição

Quando eu devo usar o operador ternário `?` em C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int valor, resultado;

    printf("\nValor: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    resultado = valor < 10 ? 50 : 0;

    printf("\nResultado = %d", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Não esta muito claro para mim como é validada as condições. A estrutura dele seria:

```
variavel = decisão ? valor_verdadeiro : valor_falso
```

Tenho duvidas também a respeito do `:`, ele também é um operador? Ou ele só é usado em conjunto com o `?` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O operador condicional é o `? :`, não são dois operadores. Como ele é ternário, ele tem duas partes para separar, como você bem observou: a condição, o valor para verdadeiro e o valor para falso.

Ele também é chamado de [operador ternário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), mas não gosto do termo. Se um dia tiver outro ternário, gera confusão, e este nome não diz o que ele faz, é terminologia ruim.

De uma certa forma ele é um substituto para o `if`, pelo menos quando apenas se quer pegar um valor de acordo com a decisão. Obviamente ele não pode executar comandos, só pode executar expressões. E se ficar muito complicado, apesar de ainda funcionar, ele fica ilegível, especialmente se tiver várias condições aninhadas.

Então use apenas quando cabe uma expressão simples e não vai aninhar. É comum usar parênteses na condição mesmo quando não é necessário. Outras vezes usa-se parênteses em toda a expressão do operador:

```
resultado = ((valor < 10) ? 50 : 0);
```

Claro que neste caso é exagero, é simples o suficiente para não causar confusão. Mas se esta expressão fizesse parte de outra expressão, já ficaria mais confuso sem parênteses. E obviamente em alguns casos ele se torna obrigatório para atingir o que deseja sem ter problemas de [precedência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Eu prefiro assim em casos simples, mas tem que prefira fazer:

```
if (valor < 10)
{
    resultado = 50;
}
else
{
    resultado = 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/ConditionalAlternative.c).

Partindo do princípio que a variável já está declarada, porque se for primeiro uso, e geralmente seria, então ainda ficaria uma linha com o operador condicional e teria uma linha a mais na forma do `if`.

Veja mais em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4907/101), a linguagem é diferente mas funciona igual. [Tem essa também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3647/101).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, ficou mais claro agora. Realmente sem parentes ele confunde e fica difícil de ler, vou procurar usar ele com  mais cuidado e em apenas em casos específicos.