# Eliminando espaços em excesso de um texto

Tags: c, string

Tenho o código de uma função que deveria ajustar espaço na frase, porém a mesma não está funcionando.

Gostaria de fazer com *input* de usuário da mesma forma que a função que remove funciona.

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte frase:

input: `meu      codigo     em       C    para     ajustar       espaços`.

O retorno deveria ser: `meu codigo em C para ajustar espaços`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void rSpace(char *string)
{

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int tam = strlen(string);

    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if(string[i] != ' ') {
            string[j] = string[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

   string[j] = '\0';
}

void jSpace(char *string)
{
    char blank[1000];
    int c = 0, d = 0;

    while(string[c] != '\0') 
    {
        if (string[c] == ' ') 
        {
            int temp = c + 1;

            if (string[temp] != '\0') 
            {
                while (string[temp] == ' ' && string[temp] != '\0') 
                {
                    if (string[temp] == ' ') 
                    {
                        c++;
                    }

                    temp++;
                }
           }
        }

        blank[d] = string[c];
        c++;
        d++;
    }

    blank[d] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    //char frase[200] = "minha   frase com   algums     espaços";
    //rSpace(frase); //output: minhafrasecomalgumsespaços OK
    //printf("%s\n", frase);

    char frase2[200] = "minha   frase com   algums     espaços";

    //output: minha frase com algums espaços //ERRO não esta validando ajustes no espaço
    jSpace(frase2);

    printf("%s\n", frase2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recomendo você procurar algoritmos de trim, tem vários já implementados e muito bons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava no caminho certo, só precisava achar a condição que determinaria se o espaço deve ou não ser copiado. Sabendo disto o algoritmo pode ser bem simples.

O que deve copiar? Todos caracteres **diferentes de espaço OU o caractere anterior (último analisado) seja diferente de espaço**. Afinal se o último era um espaço já é suficiente, não preciso dos outros.

Obviamente precisa de uma variável para controlar qual é o último caractere analisado.

Este algoritmo ainda tem um problema e vou deixar para você resolvê-lo. Se tiver espaços no início e no fim da frase o normalmente seria eliminar todos espaços e atualmente está deixando um. Depois se não conseguir ou não tiver certeza que está correto e simples (é muito importante fazer algoritmos simples, o seu `jSpace()` estava cada vez mais maluco) poste uma nova pergunta com o código pra gente analisar. Mas primeiro tente fazer.

#### Dicas:

- para eliminar o primeiro só tem que fazer uma pequena alteração no início da função, não precisa adicionar ou eliminar nada, só mudar
- para eliminar o último espaço precisa fazer uma verificação no final da função, se souber usar o [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92101/101), não vai acrescentar uma linha sequer ao algoritmo.

Note que eu [eliminei o `strlen()`, quase nunca é necessário usá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101) e é melhor assim.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rSpace(char *string) {
    int j = 0;
    char last = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] != ' ' || last != ' ') {
            string[j] = string[i];
            j++;
            last = string[i];
        }
    }
   string[j] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char frase2[200] = "minha   frase com   algums     espaços";
    rSpace(frase2);
    printf("%s\n", frase2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/b22Xwz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iipwsksi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Trim.c).

Comment: legal cara valeu eu tentei de varias formas mas fiquei meio perdido e acabei nao entendendo bem desulpa a demora é que eu tava de viagem e nao pude acessar o meu notebook agora sim ta tudo certo...

Comment: a minha função jSpace ja consegui resolver

Comment: @dark777 não tem problema, dá uma olhada no [tour] para entender como a gente funciona. Você pode aceitar e votar a resposta.