# O que significa esses operadores " > " e " ? "

Tags: c++, operadores

O código abaixo é parte de um algoritmo que mostra a altura de uma árvore binária:

```
int left = height(p->left);
int right= height(p->right);
int larger = (left > right? left : right);
return 1 + larger;
```

O que significa essa parte `(left > right? left : right)`?

Comment: O `cond? case_true: case_false` é o operador ternário. Retorna `case_true` caso a condição em `cond` seja verdadeira, retorna `case_false` no caso contrário. A condição é se `left > right`, número da esquerda maior que o da direita. Ele retorna o número da esquerda caso seja verdadeiro, e o da direita caso contrário. Ou seja, pega o maior dos dois

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` significa maior que, igual em todas as linguagens e na matemática (ainda que costuma ser uma afirmação e em programação é uma pergunta que gerará um resultado booleano. Neste caso está perguntando se o valor de `left` é maior que o valor de `right`.

O resultado decidirá o que fazer com o próximo operador que é ternário (no momento o único assim), ou seja, ele tem três partes. O nome dele é [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92101/101). Então o valor da segunda parte (após o `?` será o resultado de toda expressão se a condição anterior for verdadeira. Se for falsa o resultado será a última parte, ou seja, o que está depois do `:`. Esse resultado será guardado em `larger`.

Então ele é como se fosse um `if`, mas é uma expressão.

Este código poderia ser escrito assim:

```
int left = height(p->left);
int right= height(p->right);
if (left > right) return 1 + left;
else return 1 + right
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/ConditionalAsIf.c).

Answer (score 0):

A equivalência disso seria:

```
int larger;
if(left > right){
    larger = left;
}else{
    larger = right;
}
```

O nome dessa instrução de código:

```
int larger = (left > right? left : right);
```

se chama Instrução Condicional Ternária.

Answer (score 0):

```
int larger = (left > right ? left : right)
```

No modo simples

```
(condição ? verdadeiro : falso)
```

antes do **?** seria a condição
e entre **:** a resposta