# Erro: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf'

Tags: c, declaração-de-variável, printf, dev-c++, argumento

Possuo essa atividade, exercício,  onde é pra exibir o maior número, mas tá dando o erro:

> ```
> "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf' "
> ```

Na linha do comando `"printf (valor2);"`.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()

{
   double valor1, valor2;
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor1);
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor2);
    if ( valor1>valor2)
   {
      print ( valor1);
    }
      else if (valor1< valor2)
     {
        printf (valor2)
      }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Possuem vários erros no seu código, acredito que por você ser iniciante!
Recomendo ler  sobre [funções printf e scanf](https://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rodolfo/aedsi-2-10/printf_scanf/printfscanf.html)

Leia esta resposta também [Diferença entre %i e %d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152401/110782)

Seu código funcional fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
   double valor1, valor2;
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor1);
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor2);
    if ( valor1>valor2){             
      printf("%f", valor1);
            }
      else if (valor1 < valor2){
            printf("%f", valor2);
      }
}
```

Apenas uma pequena dica, como você irá comparar apenas 2 variáveis, poderia fazer com a estrutura `if-else` em vez de `if-elseif`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
   double valor1, valor2;
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor1);
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor2);
    if ( valor1>valor2){             
      printf("%f", valor1);
            }
      else {
            printf("%f", valor2);
      }
}
```

Conforme lembrado pelo Gato, há ainda uma terceira possibilidade usando operador ternário, ou operador condicional:

Leia nesta pergunta: [Quando devo usar o operador “?” em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92101/quando-devo-usar-o-operador-em-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
   double valor1, valor2, resultado;
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor1);
   scanf ( "%lf", &valor2);
   resultado = valor1 > valor2 ? valor1 : valor2;
   printf("%f", resultado);

}
```

Comment: Neste caso, o uso do operador ternário também poderia ser útil para melhorar a legibilidade do código.

Comment: @gato bem lembrado! Acha recomendável postar sua pergunta para ele? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92101/quando-devo-usar-o-operador-em-c

Comment: Pode citar na sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seja um erro de sintaxe no `printf`, tente escrever da seguinte maneira:

```
printf("%d", valor2)
```

Note também que utilizou o `print(valor1)` e mudou para print"f"(valor2).