# função rand() em C

Tags: c

Ola,

Vi esta linha em um código na net e estou a ter dificuldades em perceber o que faz ao certo.

(rand() % 9 == 4) ? 4 : 2;

eu sei que dá o valor 4 ou 2

Mas o que está a fazer o "% 9 == 4", o  " ? ", e o " ? 4 : 2" ?

Será que alguem consegue explicar?

Comment: Seja bem vindo. O que você procura está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92101/quando-devo-usar-o-operador-em-c

Comment: Rand retornará um numeró aleatório, o percetual será responsável pelo resto da divisão e o interrogação junto com os dois pontos fazem parte de um operador ternário.